# Academic Honesty for Teaching Staffs (Case Study)

Tags: graduate-admissions, ethics, plagiarism

I want to share a case study with you.

Peter received a Bachelor's Degree from ABC University.

Later, he wanted to pursue a higher degree (e.g. MPhil degree) and found a potential supervisor in the field of topic that he felt interested in ABC University.  Let's call her Susan.

Peter read some papers suggested by his potential supervisor (Susan) and worked with her to draft a research proposal in the topic relating to "A" for his MPhil degree application.

At the same time, she was preparing a draft conference paper in the topic relating to "B" with her research group members and some researchers from other university for paper publishing.

For some reasons, she told Peter to use this draft as his research proposal for his MPhil degree application, so he could be admitted easily, and explained that the research topic could be changed once he got admitted.

Later, Peter followed her instructions, got admitted but worked on the topic relating to "C" (not "A" or "B") and the paper relating to "B" was published successfully.

Although the paper relating to "B" was unpublished when a certain portion of its draft was used as the research proposal for Peter, the paper was published some months later.

Other authors for this paper may not know she used this draft as the research proposal for Peter.

Was it just an ethical issue?

Was it related to academic dishonesty?

You can search in the web and find any universities in any countries.

Their web sites will give some guidelines or information for Academic Honesty for students only.

Can I assume all teaching staff understood these guidelines when they were students?

Comment: Too many variables to follow. Can't you tell the story referring to yourself and use fake names for your colleagues, students etc?

Comment: Explained what were the guidelines I mentioned before

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that Peter's research proposal was used internally only.

It seems Susan did some slightly fancy juggling.  Unless Peter's university policies say otherwise, I don't think anyone would get in trouble for this.  Peter's options (not all mutually exclusive), as I see them:

- He could let it be water under the bridge, reasoning that research proposals often undergo substantial changes before a project is completed and published
- He could choose to avoid working with Susan long term
- He could continue to work with Susan, but plan to be on the lookout in case Susan tries to cut any corners in future in projects he is involved with
- He could have a frank, respectful conversation with Susan, share his concerns, and listen to her point of view
- He could meet with the director of graduate studies in his department, share his proposal and the published paper, and ask if there is a problem

I have no personal opinion about what option(s) Peter should choose.

Now, your question:

> Most of the guidelines for Academic Honesty are for students only.  Can I assume all teaching staff understood these guidelines when they were students?

This question is really not clear to me at all.  Assume that all teaching staff understood *which* guidelines when they were students?

Please edit the post to make the question part clearer.

*(I'm posting this as an answer rather than a comment because I needed more space for my bulleted list of options.  Even though you didn't ask what Peter's options are, I guessed that this list might be helpful for you.)*